# How to add an Image Button to scroll horizontal category list

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, android-layout

I have task to set focusable textView in `HorizontalScrollView` with image at the ends to show availability of menu. I did it by using  horizontal scroll View, but I need to place an `ImageButton` between menu(s?).  I am not able to get the `ImageButton` in between the horizontal scroll. How can I do it?

Comment: I made some edits to your question.  Please check them carefully, as I did not completely understand the post, and might have changed the meaning.

Comment: what do you mean by between menus?

Comment: i mean `leftImageButtonA` move the `HorizontalScrollView`(menu) right or left  and the other `RightImageButtonB` does the same action.